# How to put an Entry option in a Messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter program, with a normal graphic interface. I know how to display messageBox, which can ask a question, but I only know that the possible answer can be yes or no. I would like a message box which can have an Entry button, is it possible?

I don't want just to put an Entry button in my interface, I want it to "pop" at a certain moment.
Someone knows how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tkMessageBox` module provides button-only dialogs. You can use the `Toplevel` widget to create a similar effect pretty easily, and customize it to include an `Entry` widget:

```
def dialog():
    '''function to create dialog window'''
    msgbox = Toplevel() # create an instance of toplevel

    # create widgets with toplevel instance as parent
    Entry(msgbox, textvariable=var).pack()
    Button(msgbox, text='Enter', command=msgbox.destroy).pack()

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
Button(root, text='Call Dialog Box', command=dialog).pack()
Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()

mainloop()
```